# How can I scroll with a two-paned layout and a header using flexbox?

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox

I've worked with flexbox casually for a few months now in Chrome 32 and am liking what I see. But now I'm hitting a wall introducing `overflow: scroll` to my flexbox layout. `overflow: scroll` requires an explicit `height` or `min-height` to know when to start scrolling.

When I make a simple two-paned flexbox layout, I can give each pane a height of 100% of it's parent, which in turn is 100% the height of the window. Therefore, I can make one of the panes scroll when it has too much content, while the other pane doesn't scroll at all. Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/T5NC9/4/

However, once I add a header above these two panes, the two pages get pushed down by the height of the header added. It looks like the following and isn't too ideal:

http://jsfiddle.net/T5NC9/5/

I think I've gotten the hang of how flexbox and window height work together in simple cases. Can flexbox handle this, though? Should I look at the template layout instead?

**Note**: I have had some success using, say, `height: 10vh` for the header and `90vh` for the pane height. But that feels hacky.

Comment: There are lots of elements around, and I get lost trying to follow them. However, I would say that the main idea of the flexbox system is to *avoid* setting explicit heights, min-heights, and so. The *model* is flex-basis, flex-shrink, and flex-grow. If you try to use the traditional model in the flex-box model, IMHO, you are not going the correct way.

Comment: Are you saying you're able to achieve scrolling inside of flexbox without a min-height: 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can just make the `<body>` a vertical flexbox (`display:flex;flex-direction:column`), with `flex: none` on the nav and `flex: 1 0px` on the .content.

(That way, the nav will get its auto-height, and the content absorbs all of the extra space. No need for 10%/90% divisions.)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vr5Yv/

(EDIT: After the `min-height:auto` feature was reintroduced, you need to clear that on the div with id="content", too, or it ends up too tall. Updated jsfiddle with that additional change: http://jsfiddle.net/vr5Yv/5/ )

Comment: Awesome, I didn't realize that `flex: none` was key for this. Thanks!

Comment: Your fiddle is working as intended on Chrome, but it is *not* working on Firefox. Was something changed?

Comment: Yes -- the `min-width:auto` / `min-height:auto` feature was [reintroduced](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1015474), and the div with ID 'content' is ending up too tall as a result (due to the large min-content height of its children, which doesn't consider 'overflow' on the children).  Fixed jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vr5Yv/5/

Comment: (My original fiddle still "works" in Chrome likely due to this bug or a variant: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=487302 )

Comment: (This breakage was an instance of the general issue when `overflow` is set on the grandchild of a flex container, which I brought up on the CSSWG list here: https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2014Jul/0589.html .  Sadly, it seems like it's a quirk of `min-height:auto` that authors just need to watch out for & work around. :-/)